# Classic ASP number of weekdays between dates

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Is there any way in Classic ASP VBScript to get the number of weekdays between 2 dates? Obviously, we have the `DateDiff()` function but this will pull back the total number of days but I would like to omit the weekends.

Comment: Use google, lots of hits....[vbscript+count+weekends](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=-uTNW9bJFIvDgAbetb3QDw&q=vbscript+count+weekends)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, `DateDiff()` doesn't cover this but it can be used in conjunction with `WeekDay()` to work out if a `Day` falls on a weekend.

By using `DateDiff()` to get the number of days we can then use a `For` loop to step through the days using `DateAdd()` to increment the day as we go and check whether the incremented date value is a particular `WeekDay()`. We can then decide based on this outcome whether to increment a counter that is storing our resulting number of weekdays.

Below is an example of how you would do this, the main logic has been encapsulated in a Function that you could include in a `#include` script file to use in multiple pages.

```vb
<%
Function DateDiffWeekDays(d1, d2)
    Dim dy: dy = 0
    Dim dys: dys = DateDiff("d", d1, d2)
    Dim isWeekDay: isWeekDay = False
    Dim wkd
    Dim wd: wd = 0

    For dy = 0 To dys
        wkd = Weekday(DateAdd("d", dy, d1))
        isWeekDay = Not (wkd = vbSunday Or wkd = vbSaturday)
        If isWeekDay Then wd = wd + 1
    Next
    DateDiffWeekDays = wd
End Function

'Example of how to call the function and output to the page
Call Response.Write(DateDiffWeekDays(Date(), CDate("12 Nov 2018")))
%>
```

Output:

```
16
```

This is just a  quick example and doesn't cover every possible usage case, the idea is it gives you a starting point that you can work from and improve.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript does not include the requested operation, but as `DateDiff` with a `ww` interval returns the number of Sundays between two dates, ensuring that start and end dates are out of the weekend we can directly calculate the number of working days:

```vbs
Option Explicit

Function WorkingDaysBetween( ByVal d1, ByVal d2 )
Dim d
    ' Adjust date order to simplify calcs and always return 0 or positive number
    If d1 > d2 Then 
        d = d1 : d1 = d2 : d2 = d
    End If 

    ' Move start date forward if it is a weekend
    d = WeekDay( d1, vbMonday )
    If d > 5 Then d1 = DateAdd( "d", 3-(d\6 + d\7), d1)

    ' Move end date backward if it is a weekend
    d = WeekDay( d2, vbMonday )
    If d > 5 Then d2 = DateAdd( "d", -1*(d\6 + d\7), d2)

    ' Calculate 
    '   DateDiff("d") = Number of days between dates
    '   +1 to include start day
    '   -2 * DateDiff("ww") to exclude weekends between dates
    WorkingDaysBetween = 1 + DateDiff("d", d1, d2, vbMonday) - 2*DateDiff("ww", d1, d2, vbMonday)

    ' If the result is negative, there are no working days between both dates
    If WorkingDaysBetween < 0 Then WorkingDaysBetween = 0
End Function
```